# phpMyAdmin Error - Says my table does not have a unique column when it has two

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin is displaying:

```
 Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and 
 Delete features are not available.
```

It displays this even when I have a unique column. In fact, I have two:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Rest_Details` (
 `Resturant_ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Resturant_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Resturant_des` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `Res_Address_Line_1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `Res_Address_Line_2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `City_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Resturant_Postcode` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Cat_ID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
 `Avg_Del` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
 `Est_Del` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
 `Email1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `Email2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Min_ord` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Resturant_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Resturant_name` (`Resturant_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Resturant_ID` (`Resturant_ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I believe this is causing countless problems with inserting data and selecting data from the table in question. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why is Resturant_ID a bigint(255)? There aren't enough restaurants in the world to overflow a plain old 32-bit integer.

Comment: Also, you should remove the unique key on Resturant_ID because it's redundant with the primary key on the same column. Primary keys must be unique.

Comment: Where exactly are seeing this error? This looks like something that has less to do with the table and more to do with what you're selecting on.

Comment: Perhaps making the 2 changes I mentioned above will be enough to help PHPMyAdmin to be less confused about your table.

Comment: @Asaph the website is a for franchises, some franchises have 34 restaurants each, that is why it is 255.  I actually due to take the unique key of the iD, i was just testing it out due to the fact, the table seemed to be causing so much issues. but thank you

Comment: @NathanielFord see that is my issue, i put my script up here yesterday thinking that myself, and i was told there is nothing wrong with my code. So I'm am so confused and frustrated at the moment

Comment: @Asaph just made those changes, still the same problem